# Moodle Accept Login from external site from external website

Tags: php, yii2

We are adding Moodle to our site (different server, different sub-domain, but same main domain, and the servers are set up to be able to communicate with each other) and what we want to have it do is:

1. if the User accesses the main site
2. User logs in User clicks a link to Moodle
3. The user is automatically logged into Moodle without
   having to reenter their info.

i have added the html form with hidden type in my main domine as moodle post url.

Main domine:

```
<form class="mt-3" action="http://localhost/moodle/login/index.php" method="post" id="login">
<input id="anchor" type="hidden" name="anchor" value="">
<script>document.getElementById('anchor').value = location.hash;</script>
<input type="hidden" name="logintoken" value="xUe9G7a012vTHpvtOxAfzu84YJ046pu4">
<input type="hidden" name="loginhas" value="eda690fdf">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username / email</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" value="admin" placeholder="Username / email" autocomplete="username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="eda690fdf" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password">
</div>
<div class="rememberpass mt-3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberusername" id="rememberusername" value="1">
    <label for="rememberusername">Remember username</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3" id="login">Log in</button>
```

How to accept this request in moodle ? or if you have any rolution regarding this issue plese help me out of this.

Comment: Hello Harsha and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add the moodle version you're running?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if possible with Moodle. We do it for several systems using CAS (central authentication service), where several yii2 apps login against a CAS implemented with web2py.

In the Yii side we use https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-usuario for user management and https://github.com/daxslab/yii2-cas-client for auth against the CAS.

Perhaps you need to implement a CAS on Yii and check how make that Moodle authenticates against it.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Authentication. You'll probably need a CAS/SSO server

Comment: Yes, there is CAS there and also external database that looks interesting...